# Relation between rank of a linear transformation and pullback ($r$-linear forms.)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

> **Problem.** The rank of the linear transformation $A: S \to U$ is the largest integer $r$ such that $A^{*}: \mathcal{A}_{r}(U) \to \mathcal{A}_{r}(S)$ is not equal to zero.

**Notations.**

- $\mathcal{A}_{r}(S)$ denotes the vector space of $r$-linear forms over $S$.
- $A^{*}$ is defined by
  $$(A^{*}\omega)(v_{1},...,v_{r}) = \omega(A\cdot v_{1},...,A\cdot v_{r}),$$
  for $\omega \in \mathcal{A}_{r}(U)$ and $v_{i} \in S$. The transformation $A^{*}$ is the *induced* by $A$ in the forms of
  degree $r$ and the form $A^{*}\omega$ is the *pull-back* of the form
  $\omega$ to space $S$.

---

**Idea.** Let $r$ the largest integer such that $A^{*}$ is not zero and rank$(A) = m$. Given a set $C = \lbrace v_{1},...,v_{k} \mid v_{i} \in S\rbrace$ with $k > m$ so, $C$ is linearly dependent over $S$. Thus there is $i \neq j$ such that $v_{i} = \alpha v_{j}$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore
$$\omega(v_{1},...,v_{i},...,v_{j},...,v_{k}) = \omega(v_{1},...,\alpha v_{j},...,v_{j},...,v_{k}) = 0,$$
then $r \leq m$.

Now, if $\tilde{C} = \lbrace v_{1},...,v_{k} \mid v_{i} \in S \rbrace$ with $k \leq m$ we can suppose $\tilde{C}$ LI, since rank$(S) = m$. Thus,
$$\omega(v_{1},...,v_{k}) \neq 0$$
since $v_{i}$ are LI. Then $\omega \neq 0$.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean *alternating* linear forms? Otherwise you cannot follow that $\omega(\ldots,v_j,\ldots,v_j,\dots) = 0$. Also, $C$ might still be linearly independent, you only know that $AC$ is linearly dependent in $U$.

Comment: @red_trumpet, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by $\mathcal{A}_r(U)$, you actually mean *alternating* linear forms.

Then your proof is a bit vague in the details, but the general idea is right.

First we don't know, if $C$ is linearly dependent in $S$, because $C$ is arbitrary and we know nothing about the dimension of $S$.

But we know, that $AC = \{ Av_i \mid i \}$ is linearly dependent in $U$. So now we get
$$ (A^*\omega)(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \omega(Av_1,\dots,Av_k) = 0,$$
for any $\omega \in \mathcal{A}_r(U)$. Thus $r \le m$.

In the other direction you take a linearly independent set $C$, such that $AC$ remains linearly independent. This is possible, because $|C| \le \text{rank}(A)$. Now we need at least one form $\omega \in \mathcal{A}_k(U)$, which does not vanish on $AC$. Such a form exist, for example you might complete $AC$ to a basis of $U$ and then take the determinant. Thus $A^*\omega(v_1,\dots,v_k) = \omega(Av_1,\ldots,Av_k) \neq 0$.